# Xamarin android hung up outgoing call?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to hung up the outgoing call from android, but i can't detect `CALL_STATE_RINGING`.

Here my code sample:

```
[BroadcastReceiver()]      
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL", "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE", "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE_CHANGED" })]
        class CallListener : BroadcastReceiver
        {           
            public CallListener()
            {

            }

            public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                 if (state == TelephonyManager.ExtraStateRinging)
                 {
                      //some code here 
                 }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the `[BroadcastReceiver]` attribute?

Comment: @Cheesebaron no, i don't missing that attribute in the project.

Comment: So you hit OnReceive, but you are uncertain about how to get the current state, or what is the question?

Comment: @Cheesebaron, I want detect when take  a call on the other side.

Comment: But what is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: When anybody take a call on the other side, OnReceive don't catch anything.

Answer (score 0):

Recheck your intent filter, it must be incorrect. Validate it with working android java samples / android doc.

Also yhou should not use strings, Xamarin has all these strings turned into consts. The hard thing is to find them. Check them on TelephonyManager class.